# VS Xamarin Agent losing build host connection

Tags: xamarin

I’m having an issue for the 3rd time now! VS loses connection to the mac build host. Trying to remember how it happened the other times I think it might be related to updates. Yesterday I updated to Parallels 12 and the new OSX version, 10.11.6. Please take a look at my pictures and let me know if you’ve been in this situation and how you solved.

The other times I fixed by try-and-error, so I have no idea about what was the actual fix…

By the way, I can ping, remote login is enabled and mono is set as allowed in the firewall.

[image]

[image]

Ping mac host:

[image]

Remote login:

[image]

Firewall:

[image]

PuTTY SSH working:

[image]

Everything said here is done:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/#Configuration

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Well, from the moment I posted this question to now it started to work again. But instead of closing this answer I'm gonna leave it open until we can find a solution for this. I'm not the only one facing this issue and it would be cool to document it for the next time it happens.

Here's the connection working now... :

[image]

Comment: You are connected to the mac by cable or wifi?

Comment: @MarcosJoséPérezPérez Parallels

Comment: What if you connect by IP and not by DNS name?

Comment: Check the log/  help -> xamarin -> open logs.
-----------------------------------------------------------
Check you have the same version of Xamarin in the Mac OS and Windows.

Comment: @MarcosJoséPérezPérez cool, just one sec

Comment: @valdetero I'll check, just one sec

Comment: Well, it is working now (check my updated answer) but if you have more ideas I'm willing to check that. I'd rather get to the bottom of it this time.

Comment: @valdetero not the issue, I was able to ping the name :/

Comment: @MarcosJoséPérezPérez yes I do.

Comment: I think the problem is related with intermittent network.

Comment: @MarcosJoséPérezPérez but why only when I update the OS?

Comment: may be you are working with dynamic ip. I don't know, I have the last version of the captain and I don't have any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're including some reliability improvements on the connectivity between Visual Studio and the Mac build host as part of Xamarin for Visual Studio 4.2.0.
If you hit this issue again, please let me know what Xamarin version are you using, and also share the logs after the failing connection. (Help - Xamarin - Zip Logs).

If the issue is DNS related, you can try connecting by IP (adding the Mac manually) as suggested by @valtedero.

Another interesting test to diagnostic the issue is [trying to build an iOS project from a developer command line](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/#Command_Line_Support), passing the *ServerAddress*, *ServerUser* and *ServerPassword*. That will try to connect to the Mac using the same mechanism used by Visual Studio without interference of editors, extensions or any other Visual Studio artifacts.

Finally, if you're not using the latest Xamarin version (currently 4.2.0) please give it a try, it does not only includes connectivity improvements, but it also improves the tracing around connectivity, which can give us valuable information to diagnostic other potential issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this update available in the stable channel or only beta? The last version I have installed (even after force-checking) is 4.1.2.18

Comment: Hi @eestein, this update is currently only in Beta and Alpha channels (4.2.0.x). Please keep in mind that you will need to switch channel on the Mac machine as well.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for keeping this open.  I have had issues with Xamarin connectivity to the mac for almost two years; keep giving up and trying again...  using the latest everything, including Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: +1 for using msbuild without VS; that was able to connect properly for me and I learned that there were more issues on the Mac side.